# Typescript function returns string instead of number

Tags: typescript

I'm rewriting some code from Javascript to Typescript (and learning Typescript too).

I have the following class:

```
export class Ticket {
  private ticketNumber: number;
  private thirdPartyId: number;

  public constructor(ticketNumber: number, thirdPartyId: number) {
    this.ticketNumber = ticketNumber;
    this.thirdPartyId = thirdPartyId;
  }

  public getThirdPartyId = (): number => {
    return this.thirdPartyId;
  };
 }
```

`thirdPartyId` is always a number (for example '12345') but it is passed as a string to the constructor because it comes directly from the json response of a third-party API.

When I call the function `getThirdPartyId()` and I check the typeof, it's always string instead of number.

I'm enforcing returning a number in `getThirdPartyId()`, and also in the constructor, so why `this.thirdPartyId` is a string instead of number?

What is the best way to make sure to return a number? returning `Number(this.thirdPartyId)` feels redundant imo.

Thanks!

Comment: As written none of the code presented here has the problem; it's whatever is actually calling `new Ticket()`; is that code you're turning to TypeScript also?  Or is it runtime-only code?

Comment: You aren't "enforcing" anything at runtime, it seems like you have fundamentally misunderstood how Typescript works. If you want to pass it in as a string from the API then your type annotation should say `string` instead of `number`. If you want it to be a number then you have to convert it to a number (e.g. using `Number(...)`).

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4BUCWCDWw8A3gFBxxhQ4BuKMwcA+jHoTAHICuAtgEbAoALjgA7XgKgBucpWp0GzGAAscUACYAFFLACeASXUjx-QTNlgufJHkQRRaGFC4IY0ABSsCRbqeFiJQQAaOBU1LR0YAyM4R2pRAHMASjgyCgowtAA6FjYfQKg4AF5QvM4CmXTQ1WyWVQ1tPUNiuF9JT3qIpvUkyrgAX1ILKxsEOASiavDGqOb3FOI4AHoluH04FHUaHDRGXQguUIg4Ll3qxgmYBihZCigiLihRKdqwhsjovv7KwdIgA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> thirdPartyId is always a number (for example '12345') but it is passed as a string to the constructor because it comes directly from the json response of a third-party API.

Then the type of that piece of data extracted from JSON isn't been communicated to TypeScript correctly. Perhaps it is typed as `number` or `any`.

TypeScript only enforces types at compile type, and it throw errors if they are incompatible.

It can't stop you from bypassing the type system using external data at run time.

---

> What is the best way to make sure to return a number? returning Number(this.thirdPartyId) feels redundant imo.

"best" is rather subjective.

Explicitly converting to a number when you return is one approach.

I'd look to fixing the value passed to the constructor so that it matches the type you defined for the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Typescript doesn't enforce anything at runtime, as it just compiles down to pure js, and since, as you mention, the constructor takes data from an external source, it can't type-check it at lint-time.

JSON-parsed data is of type `any` by default.

The way to fix this is to either validate the data and transform it to a number before passing it to the constructor, or to take `string` in the constructor and validate/transform it there.

```js
  public constructor(ticketNumber: string, thirdPartyId: string) {
    this.ticketNumber = parseFloat(ticketNumber);
    this.thirdPartyId = parseFloat(thirdPartyId);
  }
```